# How to extract information from a word document using Python

Tags: python, dataframe, ms-word

I am working on a project where there is an application form, which is a word document, with fields such as Name, Designation, Annual Salary and so on. This form is to be filled in by applicants, and once submitted, I want to run a python script on the file to extract those values and put them in a python dataframe, so that the values can be used accordingly by using the key (Name, Designation, Annual Salary and so on)

I am not sure what libraries to be used, and not sure how to extract only the necessary info out to the dataframe

Comment: Have you tried to Google|Bard search first? The best questions are those where you show what you tried and the community will help. For example Bing’s Bard search https://g.co/bard/share/39ce988b41f5

Comment: [`python-docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  documentation is a good place to start.